# How does one create a new tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I’m now allowed to create tags, and I have a new one I’d like to create.  But I don’t know what procedure to follow in order to create a tag.

The tag I’d like to create would be for “computer-related” queries.  The explanation for the tab would be:

> Questions on or about how to use a computer as an aid in learning how to read, write, and speak the German language.

I envision that some sample questions would be something like these few:

- > How do I change my English QWERTY keyboard to a German keyboard layout?
- > For any given font, What Alt+nnnn keyboard inputs will generate the ligatures 'ch', 'ck', 'tz', and 'sz'?  [*for example, Alt + 0223 generates 'ß'*]
- > What is a source where I can both read German text and at the same time hear those words spoken in good German?
- > How can I convert Google and Amazon websites for German language input and output?
- > How do I use my computer to translate German words, phrases, and sentences to English, and the reverse translations?
- > How can I get my computer to generate Fraktur and Sütterlin fonts?"
- > Can I use Fraktur font in my emails?

Having spent many years in the computer programming and applications world, I can’t help but see computers as an excellent language-teaching and -learning aid.  And so, will someone point out where I can find directions on how to insert new tags?

Comment: You create a tag simply by using it. I did not answer yet because here I feel that we should ask the community whether they find this tag useful or even may have other suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your proposed tag would have a large common subset with the existing [tag:resources] tag. Could you please elaborate why we should introduce a _new_ tag? (Please rather edit your question than answer as comment.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm really on the fence about this suggestion, because most of these (example) questions are not specific to the German Language, but are rather questions pertaining to the use of computer software in general. This tag might degenerate into a collection of computer-manual snippets, which might often not even meet the general rules of what's a good GL question.

That said and in the spirit of meta, this answer posits that **the tag is not needed and should not be created**.

Comment: In formulating my query I reviewed all the tags listed in the "Computer Science" forum.  Having worked in that industry I completely understood what 96% of what all those 612+ tags meant.  Those that dealt with "software" related only to the use of various programming languages.  I believe using computers for learning German is far more specific and oriented for use this community than either "Language Learning" or "Computer Science".  Using computers to learn German is no more inappropriate than sitting in a schoolroom in a 'bricks and mortar' high school or college somewhere is.

Comment: @К. Келлогг Смиф I agree with hiergiltdiestfu. It looks like many of the questions that you envision would be a better fit for superuser.com, like this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1142924/umlaut-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-%c3%bc-on-english-us-layout . They are not specific to German, but rather to computer problems one might have with _any_ foreign language that uses other characters or that the user does not understand well.

Comment: @Matthias:  Because I have been using my desktop computer as a resource helping me learn Russian and refresh my German I know from actual experience how great a benefit my computer has been to me as a resource in language learning.  And that being said, I've found that SE's "Language Learning" community is  a much better forum for me; it's also a community in which I am allowed to create new tags.  So then, my "how to create a new tag" query still stands, but if answered properly I'll be able to use that knowledge in a more appropriate SE  community.

Answer (score -3):

Let me suggest a somewhat shorter tag [computing](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing) for that purpose. This tag would also be used on our sister sites English Language, and on French (as a tag synonym to the French word).

Comment: The sites you cite use this tag for vocabulary specific to computing. Not for computer issues specific to the respective language. Even if we decide to use this tag otherwise, it will be misused for this purpose. Thus, if we should decide to create such a tag, we should aim for a name that cannot be misinterpreted (although this may be difficult).